# Get value from pandas df with only one line

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am creating a simulator for a football dice game and I am running in to an issue in getting values from the dataframe.
My code for the result of a play is this:

```
def off_play(off_team_chart):
    off_UPCID = int(input('Enter UPCID for Offense Play: '))
    off_play = off_team_chart[off_team_chart['UPCID'] == off_UPCID]
    oRoll = dice.oDice()
    oPlay = off_play[off_play['DieRoll']==oRoll]
    print(oPlay)
    oResult = oPlay['ResultCodeID']
    oYards = oPlay['Yards']
    return oResult, oYards
```

which when run outputs the following:

```
        TeamChartDetailD  TeamChartID  UPCID  ...  ResultCodeID  Yards OutOfBounds
108292            866811          874      8  ...             8     19       False

[1 rows x 7 columns]
108292    8
Name: ResultCodeID, dtype: int64 108292    19
Name: Yards, dtype: object
```

I would like to have oResult be the int 8 and oYards be the int 19 in this scenario, the documentation for pandas seemed to suggest that I will need to know the 108292 number in order to get the value. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is printing the row index.
In order to print the return correctly, you should use the `.item()` method as follows:

```
oResult = oPlay['ResultCodeID'].item()
oYards = oPlay['Yards'].item()
```